# PyOpenGL Objects keep rotating around the origin

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

So I was just testing to see how things working in my engine, and tried to rotate an object simply using the following.

```
rot_y = Matrix44.from_y_rotation(glfw.get_time() * 0.5)
```

But... It rotates around the origin instead of it's place.

Main code:
http://hatebin.com/rtuqgeqptw

```
projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60.0, w_width/w_height, 0.1, 100.0)
sphere_model = matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([-4.0,0.0,-3.0]))
monkey_model = matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([0.0,0.0,-3.0]))

glUseProgram(shader)
model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model")
view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "proj")

glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.poll_events()
    do_movement()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    view = cam.get_view_matrix()
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, view)

    rot_y = Matrix44.from_y_rotation(glfw.get_time() * 0.5)

    glBindVertexArray(sphere_vao)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sphere_tex)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, rot_y *sphere_model)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(sphere_obj.vertex_index))
    glBindVertexArray(0)

    glBindVertexArray(monkey_vao)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, monkey_tex)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, monkey_model)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(monkey_obj.vertex_index))
    glBindVertexArray(0)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

glfw.terminate()
```

I'm not sure what the problem is and why it's not rotating around it's own point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the model rotates around the origin of the mesh, then you have to apply the rotation matrix before the model matrix. First rotate the model then translate it.
Further note, that the return type of [`matrix44.create_from_translation`](https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_matrix.html) is `numpy.array`. This means you have to make a `Matrix44` first, before you can multiply the matrices.

Swap the translation and the rotation matrix to solve your issue:

```
sphere_model = matrix44.create_from_translation(Vector3([-4.0,0.0,-3.0]))

rot_y = Matrix44.from_y_rotation(glfw.get_time() * 0.5)

# roation before tranasltion
model_mat = Matrix44(sphere_model) * rot_y
glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, model_mat)
```

Note the matrix multiplication has to be read form the right to the left. See also [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)

`translate * rotate`:

[image]

`rotate * translate`:

[image]

Comment: That my my thing spawn at the origin and is going weird. Its becoming a 2d Object then expanding to a sphere then it repeats

Comment: @AhmedMerabet What does your vertex shader do?

Comment: `layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 textureCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

out vec2 newTexture;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    newTexture = vec2(textureCoords.x, 1 - textureCoords.y);
}`

Comment: @AhmedMerabet It has to be `Matrix44(sphere_model) * rot_y` - see the changes to the answer

Comment: @AhmedMerabet The `*` is defined for `Matrix44() * Matrix44()` see [Matrices](https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oo_api_matrix.html). `numpy.array * Matrix44()` would do a multiplication of the single components.